# C++ 17 class template argument type deduction - readability

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction, c++17

For compilers that support this feature you can write

```
std::tuple t1(1);
```

but in my opinion in this case the readability of this program is hurt.

For instance if you have own class that behaves similarly to std::tuple, readers don't see that different instances of this template class could be of different type

```
Myple t1(1);
Myple t2(1, 2);
Myple t3(1, 3);
...
t1 == t2; // compiler error, t1 and t2 are actually of different types
t2 == t3; // no error
```

**Are there any proposals how to eliminate this "readability" problem?**

My suggestion would be to make programmers write something like this

```
Myple<auto...> t1(1);
```

( or even Myple<...> t1(1); )

so the program readers will be at least aware, cause they know that 2 different auto's can be of different types.

But I'm sure there could be smarter solutions.

**Edit**

Changed "user experience" to "readability".

Comment: What problem? If you don't like it, don't use it. You can still spell out the template arguments. Nobody took it away.

Comment: @StoryTeller: You still have to read other people's code. I don't agree with his notion that this is bad "UX", but you can't merely say "don't like, don't use" when you have to deal with people who *do* like it.

Comment: @NicolBolas - I don't recall ever working on a project that didn't have some style guidelines. If it means so much to the OP, they should speak out. And anyway, nothing they propose here will ever make code already written this way unwrite itself.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "user experience" problem refers.  The `t1 == t2;` is a compiler error, as it ought to be.  The `t2 == t3;` is not a compiler error, also working correctly.

Comment: If you write variable declarations in the `auto varname = ...;` form, this isn't as much of a problem, as `auto varname = std::tuple{1, 2};` looks like `auto varname = std::make_tuple(1, 2);` if you squint your eyes right

Comment: I dont really understand what is specific to being able to write `Myple t1(1);`. Isnt it the same with any `auto`? If you see in code `auto x = foo();` and `auto y = bar();` then either you know of what types `x` and `y` are or the compiler will tell you latest when you try `x= y;`

Comment: btw that comment was really a question (and not aiming to suggest that your question is moot). I guess you are concerned about coders being used to have variables of same type when they see declarations like `T x; T y;`

Comment: I do not see this a problem, I see it is a benefit. For me, `std::tuple x` is much better than `std::tuple<auto..> x`. Less typing, better signal to noise.

Comment: Fyi, if you're interesting in writing such a proposal, just having `tuple<...> a(1);` be the same thing as `tuple a(1);` doesn't have much merit. But having `tuple<int, ...> b(2.0, 3, 4)` be a `tuple<int, int, int>` might have potential. This would end up allowing the `tuple<...>` syntax you want, but in a way that adds new functionality.

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any proposals how to eliminate this "user experience" problem?

As of this writing, there have been [no proposal written suggesting that this be changed](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/). C++17 is done, finished, and out the door. Any such proposals removing this feature would therefore be backwards-incompatible with C++17.

And therefore, such proposals would need to justify themselves with more than merely calling it a "'user experience' problem".

It is clear from the [earliest revisions of the class template deduction proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3602.html) that the *goal* was to create the UX which you consider bad, to allow class template arguments to be deduced "exactly" like function template arguments. Even when ["challenges" with the proposal were addressed](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4471.html), there did not seem to be any suggestion that explicit syntax beyond the template name be required to invoke class template argument deduction.

In short, the goal of the proposal is to [allow constructors to "deduce their template parameters 'like we expect from other functions and methods,'"](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0091r0.html).

So it is not merely that there have been no proposals to eliminate this "'user experience' problem"; it's that this "'user experience' problem" *is the whole point* of the idea.

Comment: The point of the idea was to make it unnecessary to enumerate template parameters. But I think it created a different (readability) problem, when 2 vars look like they have same type and actually they don't. That's why I would prefer to see Myple<auto...>. It would tell me that the type I see here is not what it looks like.

Comment: And I realize that you cannot revert C++17 standard because it's out. But it's not impossible to add a new way to use this feature.

Comment: @Alek86: "*The point of the idea was to make it unnecessary to enumerate template parameters.*" I gave you a *direct quote* from the proposal as to what the "point of the idea was". You may have had a different idea, but not the people who actually made this proposal and got it standardized. "*it's not impossible to add a new way to use this feature.*" Which will change *nothing* about code that uses it the old way, so the UX "problem" you feel exists will still exist. C++ does not need more ways to do the same thing.